# Communicating with serial device over multi-drop bus

Tags: serial-port, multidrop-bus

I'm new to serial communication. For a project I have to develop software for a vending machine. The vending machine basically consists of a host computer (a windows xp machine) and various peripherals. One of those peripherals is a coin acceptor. According to the documentation of the vending machine, the host computer communicates with the coin acceptor using the serial port. The only documentation I have is this document called "Multi-Drop Bus / Internal Communication Protocol" (the version I have can be found here: http://www.coin-acceptor.com.cn/Upload/EditorFiles/technicalfile/Mdb_version_4-2.pdf).

According to the docs it seems I have to create a serial port connection using a baud rate of 9600, 1 start bit, 1 stop bit, 1 mode bit and 8 data bits (page 29 in the linked document). The vending machine docs state that the coin acceptor is on COM port 6. I tried to create a connection like this using HyperTerminal and Putty. My first question is:

1. How do I properly create a connection to a device that supports this MDB 'protocol'? Putty and HyperTerminal don't allow me to set a "mode bit". I didn't find anything about the flow control and parity bit in the document. Can this be done using Putty or HyperTerminal? Or do I need some other tool to communicate over MDB?

My second question is about how to send a command to the device. I looked through the commands and saw a RESET command. According to the document, upon receiving the RESET command the device should reset itself and respond with an ACK. According to pages 33 and 63 of the document, if I want to send the RESET command to the coin acceptor, I can send the HEX value 08H over the serial line. Page 33 states that the coin changer listens to commands sent to addresses 08H until 10H (if I'm interpreting the document correctly, that is). Page 63 states that the RESET command is 08H with no data bytes. So can I just type "08H" into Putty and hit "enter" to send this command to the device? Or how can I send this command to the device over the serial line? Is this even the right approach or am I looking in the completely wrong place? The vending machine docs only contain this document for the coin acceptor. Thank you for the help!

Kind regards

Chris

Comment: It is an evil protocol, designed to give you a hard time intentionally.  And hardware vendors a market opportunity.  Getting that 9th mode bit is hard.  The only shot you have is to use the parity bit.  That does require reprogramming the UART chip on-the-fly so it switches between mark and space parity.  Doable if you use a micro-controller, quite hard to do on a PC since there's a driver in between.  Somebody probably made one, only works on his hardware of course.  Contact the vendor's association for shopping advice.

Comment: See this [answer](http://superuser.com/questions/411386/seeking-9-bit-serial-port-card-for-windows-pc/411438#411438) on serial ports capable of 9-bit data chars.  The 16950 (or 16C950) UART is the chip you want for 9-bit data.

Comment: Sheesh, sounds like a nightmare. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @cbbcloud *"Sheesh, sounds like a nightmare"* -- You should ignore the first comment.  With a 9-bit-capable UART, implementing this protocol does not seem that difficult to me.  *"So can I just type "08H" into Putty"* -- No.  You need to learn the difference between `symbols` versus `code values` versus (raw) `binary/hex values`.